# не подключается модуль model.py после загрузки существующей базы данных в Mysql в django

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-model

У меня есть существующая база данных. Я импортировал ее в django. С помощью команды `python manage.py inspectdb > models.py` я создал models.py. В нем есть таблица stations2:

```
class Stations2(models.Model):
    id_stations = models.IntegerField(db_column='ID_stations', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    name = models.TextField(db_column='Name', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    type = models.TextField(db_column='Type', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    country = models.TextField(db_column='Country', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    latitude = models.FloatField(db_column='Latitude', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    longitude = models.FloatField(db_column='Longitude', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    elevation = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    site_gaw_id = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    stations_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'stations_2'
```

соответсвенно в файле admin.py я написал:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Stations2

admin.site.register(Stations2)
```

запускаю команду `python manage.py runserver`, однако никакой таблицы в админке я не вижу.
Я пытаюсь запустить ради интереса model.py, однако получаю ошибку:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Как я понял,чтобы ее исправить, надо вставить `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings`. Однако честно говоря я так и не понял,куда надо вставлять.

Вот что у меня есть в блоке `INSTALLED_APPS`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'scrapping_2',
]
```

Вопрос: как решить данную проблему?
Вот что находится в моем проекте
[image: описание проекта]

Comment: приложение созданное в `INSTALLED_APPS` в `setting.py` добавили?

Comment: Вот я так и не понял,какое именно туда нужно приложение скинуть...Поэтому не добавил.Можете подсказать?

Comment: которое вы создали. Используя команду `python manage.py startapp name_apps`

Comment: у меня такой вопрос: я уже создал одно приложение. Его удалять? Просто там есть миграции базы данных...Или еще одно создавать?

Comment: НАписал сверху,что у меня есть в данном блоке